# Tkinter Button, button not defined in an external def function

Tags: python, tkinter

This  is the code that I'm struggling with:

```
def create_grid():
    field = tkinter.Tk()
    grid_length = 10
    grid_width = 10
    counter2 = 0
    for i in range(grid_width):
        counter = 0
        counter2 += 1
        for i in range(10):
            button = tkinter.Button(field, height=3, width=5, text="O", fg="blue")
            button.grid(row=counter, column=counter2)
            button.bind('<Button-3>', right)
            button.bind('<Button-1>', left)
            counter += 1


def left(event):
    button.config(fg="red")


def right(event):
    global button
    button.config(fg="green")
```

When a either of the functions left or right are called it returns "button is not defined"
Any Ideas?

Comment: What do you believe `button` to be defined *as*?  That's a local variable that you used a hundred times to hold each button as it was created - even if the variable still existed when you tried to use it, how could it possibly be the *right* button?  Fortunately, you don't actually need it - the `event` parameter being passed to your bindings indicates the widget that the event applies to.  Try `event.widget.config(...)` in your two handlers.

Comment: That worked perfectly, Thanks for the help :)